# How to pass a variable to coffeescript depending on build profile in mimosa

Tags: coffeescript, global-variables, preprocessor, mimosa

I have a typical mimosa front-end project with coffeescript for scripting. I want a certain variable (api path) to have different values, depending on build profile (dev or prod). How can I achieve this in mimosa?

Example of what I want:

**prod.coffee:**

```
exports.api = 'myserver'
```

**dev.coffee:**

```
exports.api = 'localhost'
```

**api-accessor.coffee**

```
config = getCurrentConfig(); # this is the part I do not know how to implement
exports.getStuff = () ->
  # here I want config.api to have different values depending on build profile
  $.ajax config.api + 'getStuff'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I want by writing a simple mimosa [plugin](https://github.com/0xorial/mimosa-coffeescript-preprocess).
With it I can write

```
/%= api %/
```

and have it replaced with a value from config.

Answer (score 1):

You can put environment variables in your build profiles.

So instead of `exports.api = "localhost"`, use `process.env.api = "localhost"`.

Then when that profile is used, those variables are attached the `env` and accessible anywhere.

That's how we've solved this sort of thing.